# Write from a Structure to a text file with C

Tags: c, file, function, save, structure

i would like to have some help with my save function - to save structure in a file that I choose what it will be called.

so my code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH  100
#define MAX_STRUCTS  100  

struct students
{
char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH]; 
char last[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
char g[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
char s[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
};

/* Load from the named file, into the `analg` array provided, but no more than `max` entries */
/* Returns the number of entries loaded */

int load(char *filename, struct students *h, int max)
{
int count = 0;  /* The number of entries we have loaded */

FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

char line[MAX_STRUCTS * 4];  /* *4 for first and last name grade and score*/

if (fp == NULL)
    return;  /* File could not be opened */

/* Read all lines, but only as long as we have available entries in the array */
while (count < max && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
{
    /* Extract the first and last names from the newly read line */
    sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s", h[count].name, h[count].last, h[count].g, h[count].s);
    count++;  /* Increase counter so we have the current size */
}

/* All done loading */
fclose(fp);

return count;  /* Return the number of entries we loaded */

}

/* Print from the structure array, there are `count` entries in the array */
void print(struct students *h, int count)
{


int i;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    /* Print the number and the names */
    /* +1 to the index, because it starts from zero and we want to print it nicely to the user and start from 1 */

    printf("%2d) %s     %s      %s  %s\n", i + 1, h[i].name, h[i].last, h[i].g, h[i].s);
    }
}


int save (struct students *h, FILE *oput, char name){

            printf("Enter file name: " );
            scanf("%s", name); 
        fwrite(h.f_name, h.last, h.s,h.g ,sizeof(struct students),1,oput);

}

int main(void)
{
    struct students h[MAX_STRUCTS];
    FILE *oput
    char choice;
    int count = 0;  /* Initialize to zero, in case user chooses `print` first */
    char filename[100];

    int coun1t;  /* The current number of entries in the array */
    int remove; /* The entry to remove (index into array, so zero based) */

    /* Move the still valid entries one step "down" in the array */
    char line[MAX_STRUCTS * 4]; 
    char name;
    do
     {
    printf("choose L for load , P for print or S for save: \n");

    /* Read input from user, as a character, while skipping leading and trailing whitespace */
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 'l':
        printf("file name? : ");
        scanf("%s", &filename);
        count = load(filename, h, MAX_STRUCTS);

        if (count == 0)
            printf("No structures loaded\n");
        else (
        printf("Data loaded\n")
        );
        break;
    case 'p':
        print(h, count);
        break;
    case 's':
        count = save(h, name, oput);
        break;
    case 'q': 
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
} while ((choice) != 'q');

return 0;
    }
```

in my text file:

```
       1)Joe Fanskol     10,4     100

       2)Marina Jake     15.5     99
```

I can not run the program, there is an error in **`int save`**  so what should I do?

Comment: fwrite takes only 4 arguments, you supply more.

Comment: Also, you're not `fopen`ing `oput` anywhere.

Comment: ok, but I dont need to ´fopen`somthing because of my file is already open in my Array in structure. so what I need is how to get what I have in structure and copy or write it to a text file

Comment: Simple: 1) you need to fopen() it (and maybe seek to the correct record-position 2) you have to fwrite() (the correct amount of the correct data) to it 3) you have to fclose() it. *corrected*

Comment: ok I do really undestand , but what should I open()? and Close()? I mean which file or what? - @wildplasser

Comment: @Fredrik , gå to the `int save` and you see my error code !!

Comment: You call save() with arguments the wrong way around, and you don't open the FILE *oput (which you're passing as char name). You try to scan a string into a char, which you do nothing with. It's full of errors I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm going to take a stab at this.  I would write it similar to this:

```
int save (struct students *h, int num_students){
    char name[1024];
    printf("Enter file name: " );
    scanf("%s", name); // Read in filename
    FILE *output = fopen(name, "w"); // open the file to write
    if (!output) {
        return -1; // error
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_students; ++i) {
        // write a line - see fprintf documentation
        fprintf(output, "%s %s %s %s\n", h[i].f_name, h[i].last, h[i].s,h[i].g);
        // I'm missing some error checks here - you should not
    }
    fclose(output); // close
    return 0;
}
```

Then you call it by passing in your students array and the number of students in the array.  I hope this at least helps you on your way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answering , Itried what you wrote and called the function in my `switch, case` but the program is crashing after I write the name and click Enter, the file name I write is saving but the program s crashing and the file is empty!

Comment: You need to be careful here - are you passing in a valid students array?  Make sure the array you pass in is valid.

Comment: thats what I did,         `case 's':
         
         
         count = save(h, num_students);
         
         
   break;`

Comment: are you calling save before you actually load students?  Are you able to print the students first?

Comment: No I'm loading first , Printing and then trying to save so when I save it the program just crashing I dont know why!!

Comment: It works now!, I had some problem with my switch code , so now it working , thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
 scanf("%s", name);
```

You enter an string into a `char name`. You dont need this `name` if you pass an open output file. Or if you need to open the file here you will need to pass `name` as a char buffer, something like `char name[MAX_FILE_NAME_LEN];`

Comment: does it matter? I mean `[MAX_FILE_NAME_LEN];` ??

Answer (score 0):

i think that script missing some ampersand '&'

```
scanf("%s", name); >> scanf("%s", &name); ?
```

Comment: if its %s , name should not be char